# how to get mailbox size in exchange 2010 database

Tags: powershell

i am trying to customize my query so that the result show only mailboxes which are 5mb or less

Get-MailboxStatistics -database ""| Sort totalitemsize -desc | select displayname,totalitemsize

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Database 'Mailbox Database 123' |
Where-Object {$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB() -le 5} | 
Sort-Object TotalItemSize -Descending | 
Select-Object DisplayName,TotalItemSize
```

Comment: Get-MailboxDatabase “Mailbox Database” | Get-MailboxStatistics | Sort totalitemsize -desc | ft displayname, totalitemsize, itemcount

Comment: That's valid as well but it doesn't let you filter based on the mailbox size :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, Get-MailboxStatistics output just a display name - not unique and cant really be used as such. The other half of the information you need is in Get-Mailbox :- found answer in following link. once you have the data on all your mailboxes, and the output can be IMPORTED into excel you can do all your sorting etc and delete whatever you dont want

if this is what you were looking for, please click this link and give the guy some credit.. i didnt come up with this, i just found it

```
#REM http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Email_Servers/Exchange/Q_27828458.html

$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited
foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes)
{
 $Mailbox | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name "MailboxSizeMB" -Value ((Get-MailboxStatistics $Mailbox).TotalItemSize.Value.ToMb())
}
$Mailboxes | Sort-Object MailboxSizeMB -Desc | Select PrimarySMTPAddress, MailboxSizeMB


#REM - to export this out -- do the following ;) enjoy (see the part where it says "Select" you can add additional fields like ALIAS etc to this)

$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited
foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes)
{
 $Mailbox | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name "MailboxSizeMB" -Value ((Get-MailboxStatistics $Mailbox).TotalItemSize.Value.ToMb())
}
$Mailboxes | Sort-Object MailboxSizeMB -Desc | Select PrimarySMTPAddress, MailboxSizeMB | Export-Csv -NoType "C:\temp\Mailboxessize.csv"
```

go to AD and pull all users *view advanced features | add column exchange mailbox store, email address
combine both these lists in excel and enjoy a smile and a coke... you just finished 1 week of work in under 20 minutes

Comment: Does the license on experts exchange allow you to pinch the answer?